Company name followed by 'our' or 'their'
When writing for a company using Australian English, should I say 'Company name recently hosted their exclusive event' or 'Company name recently hosted our exclusive event'

If you're a part of the company, you say "our". If you're not part of the company, you say "their".

There's nothing regional about this. I can't think of any differences around the use of "our" and "their" between British, Aussie, or American.


Our company or their company?

Both of those pronouns are valid. The choice is not grammatical but depends on the perspective of the writer. If he is writing as though he were an insider, it's our. If the writing is from the perspective of an outsider, it's their.
For example, suppose the company is Apple and the exclusive event is a new product launch. I would expect to read our exclusive event in an article on the company's website, but their exclusive event in a CNN news report.
Note that this is true of writer/group situations in general. We would have the same result if we were writing in the case of our/their football club, or our/their church.
